# WPF RichTexBox printing is creating unexpected line breaks

Tags: c#, wpf, printing, richtextbox

In `RichTextBox` of my WPF app, following print method is creating unexpected line breaks. **Question**: What I may be missing here, and how can we fix the issue?

For example, when I enter the following text in the RichTextBox (RTB), the RTB looks like as shown in image 1. But when I call the following two print methods the first one does not create the unexpected line breaks, but the second method does create unexpected line breaks:

**MainWindow.xaml**

```
<StackPanel>
    <RichTextBox Name="richTB" />

    <Button Click="PrintCommand1">Print RTB Content</Button>
    <Button Click="PrintCommand2">Print RTB Content</Button>
</StackPanel>
```

**Method 1**

```
private void PrintCommand1(Object sender, RoutedEventArgs args)
{
    PrintDialog pd = new PrintDialog();
    if ((pd.ShowDialog() == true))
    {
        pd.PrintVisual(richTB as Visual, "printing as visual");
    }
}
```

**Method 2**

```
private void PrintCommand2(Object sender, RoutedEventArgs args)
{
    PrintDialog pd = new PrintDialog();
    if ((pd.ShowDialog() == true))
    {
        pd.PrintDocument((((IDocumentPaginatorSource)richTB.Document).DocumentPaginator), "printing as paginator");
    }
}
```

**The text I enter** [Note: There is only one line break]

```
This is a test for testing purpose only. Another test: x6. Let us do some background and foreground colors.
This is a new line with formatting, as well.
```

**Snapshot of the RichTexBox with above text**

[image]

**Snapshot of "Print to PDF" (on Windows 10) using Method 1** [Printed correctly with one real line break]

[image]

**Snapshot of "Print to PDF" (on Windows 10) using Method 2** [Printed incorrectly with unexpected line breaks]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because of the `DocumentPaginator` class takes context of the `FlowDocument` and split in into multiple pages to get desired result some of `FlowDocument` parameters should be configured before printing:

```cs
private void PrintCommand2(Object sender, RoutedEventArgs args)
{
    var pd = new PrintDialog();
    if (pd.ShowDialog() == true)
    {
        FlowDocument doc = richTB.Document;

        // Save all settings that will be configured for printing.
        double pageHeight = doc.PageHeight;
        double pageWidth = doc.PageWidth;
        double columnGap = doc.ColumnGap;
        double columnWidth = doc.ColumnWidth;

        // Make the FlowDocument page match the printed page.
        doc.PageHeight = pd.PrintableAreaHeight;
        doc.PageWidth = pd.PrintableAreaWidth;                
        doc.ColumnGap = 5; 

        // Set the minimum desired width of the column in the System.Windows.Documents.FlowDocument.
        doc.ColumnWidth = doc.PageWidth - doc.ColumnGap - doc.PagePadding.Left - doc.PagePadding.Right;
        pd.PrintDocument(((IDocumentPaginatorSource)doc).DocumentPaginator, "A Flow Document");

        // Reapply the old settings.
        doc.PageHeight = pageHeight;
        doc.PageWidth = pageWidth;                
        doc.ColumnGap = columnGap;
        doc.ColumnWidth = columnWidth;
    }
}
```

With respect to *Matthew MacDonald* this way of the flow document content printing and more advanced techniques described in his book ***[Pro WPF 4.5 in C# Windows Presentation Foundation in .NET 4.5](https://www.apress.com/gp/book/9781430243656)*** *(Chapter 29)*.

Comment: Your suggestion worked (thank you). Minor typos. a) I used `(pd.ShowDialog()==true)` since  pd.ShowDialog() is of type `bool?` b) At two places, you certainly meant to use the variable `pd` instead of `printDialog`.

Comment: Sure. Thanks! :)